# How can i use variable when i used def function [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have small problem. When I make a new function with `def`, I want change `i` on the end of function according to some variable. Example:

```
import time

i = 2

def Happy_1():
    print("Happy Brithday to you")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Happy Brithday to you")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Happy Brithday dear Paul")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Happy Brithday to you")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("END")

def Happy_2():
    print("Happy Brithday to you")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Happy Brithday to you")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Happy Brithday dear Peter")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Happy Brithday to you")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("END")

Happy_("i or some variable")()
```

Is it possible to do something?
Thank you

Comment: Why don't you make it an argument to the function?

Comment: Because i call the function Happy_i, i don't want print. This is only example, but I explained it wrong, sorry. Thanks for your reaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
locals()["Happy_" + i]()
```

or

```
globals()["Happy_" + i]()
```

`locals()["Happy_" + i]` will get the function from the locals, and the final `()` will call the function.

Comment: Yes, i want call the function Happy_1, Happy_2, .... Happy_i, depends of variable. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure others are missing the obvious solution here.

```
def happy(i):
    names = ['Paul', 'Peter'] 
    ...
    print('Happy birthday to {}'.format(names(i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

i = 2

def Happy_1():
    print("Happy Brithday to you")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Happy Brithday to you")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Happy Brithday dear Paul")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Happy Brithday to you")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("END")

def Happy_2():
    print("Happy Brithday to you")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Happy Brithday to you")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Happy Brithday dear Peter")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Happy Brithday to you")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("END")

def error():
    print('No such function!')

print locals().get('Happy_{}'.format(i), error)()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ Daniel Roseman for pointing this.

**Zen of Python - Simple is better than complex.**

Please check this code.

- Function Happy takes one argument. So no need to write two functions.

```
import time

i = 2

def Happy(i):

     if i == 1:
         print("Happy Brithday to you")
         time.sleep(1)
         print("Happy Brithday to you")
         time.sleep(1)
         print("Happy Brithday dear Paul")
         time.sleep(1)
         print("Happy Brithday to you")
         time.sleep(1)
         print("END")
     elif i == 2:
         print("Happy Brithday to you")
         time.sleep(1)
         print("Happy Brithday to you")
         time.sleep(1)
         print("Happy Brithday dear Peter")
         time.sleep(1)
         print("Happy Brithday to you")
         time.sleep(1)
         print("END")

Happy(i)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python demo.Py
Happy Brithday to you
Happy Brithday to you
Happy Brithday dear Peter
Happy Brithday to you
END
```